# Print duplicicate string in text files

Tags: java, file

I have gone through stackoverflow but couldnot re-write the code to my requirements (I am new to Java). Help me!

I have text file in which there is a string without spaces and like that there may be n strings. 
Ex:

```
report-final.pdf--@19.5625
references.pdf--@46.25
multithread.pdf--@166.85546875
report-final.pdf--@19.5625
```

Here it is file name and size of file with delimitter(--@)

I want to print the duplicate lines(strings) from the text file(Ex.

```
 report-final.pdf--@19.5625
```

is present two times. So I want to print it. I have tried using hash set(without success) but it only prints only unique items and not the duplicate items.
**EDIT**

```
 while (read.hasNext()) {
            String line = read.nextLine();
            if(map.containsKey(line)) {
                map.put(line, map.get(line).longValue() + 1);
            } else {
                map.put(line, 1L);
            }
```

This is the code I have tried. I dont know if its correct and its not working for me though

Comment: This sounds like homework assignment. What have you tried? Where is your code?

Comment: Edit and add your code into the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`I have tried using hash set(without success) but it only prints only unique items and not the duplicate items.` ... well, because you used it wrong.

This is a possible way to achieve this task with a `Set`:

```
String[] data = new String[]{"report-final.pdf--@19.5625", "references.pdf--@46.25", "multithread.pdf--@166.85546875", "report-final.pdf--@19.5625"};
Set<String> entries = new HashSet<>();
for (String entry : data) {
    if (!entries.add(entry)) {
        System.out.println("Duplicate file entry: " + entry);
    }
}
```

[`Set#add(E)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#add%28E%29) returns true, if the element was added to the `Set` successfully, or false otherwise. We can use this to find duplicates, since trying to add them will result in a returned `false`.

You could also add these entries to another `Collection` if you like.

Comment: Ha!! This helps me a lot but I need to fetch it from file. I mean strings are in file. I'll try and post the result sir.Thank you

Comment: Thank You sir. Its working. Now fetching from file and displaying it. Thank You!!